# Анимация слайдера в css

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Делаю слайдер своими руками. Пока все получалось, слайды переключаются, всплывающий текст - работает.

А вот с анимацией пока туго. Помогите анимировать данный [слайдер](http://beta2.skynetrtx.com/index2.html). Собственно, хотелось бы получить что-то простое, например старый слайд уезжает влево, а новый появляется справа.
Код:

```css
.service .slider__checker {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.service .slider__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.service .slider__item {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#hand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  right: 67%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: url('http://facte.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/63d.jpg');
}

#head {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: url('http://facte.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/63d.jpg');
}

#foot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  right: 40%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: url('http://facte.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/63d.jpg');
}

.service .help {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

div:hover>.help {
  display: block;
}

.service .slider__checker:nth-child(1):checked~.slider__items>.slider__item:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}

.service .slider__checker:nth-child(1):checked~.slider__labels>.slider__label:nth-child(1) {
  background: white;
}

.service .slider__checker:nth-child(2):checked~.slider__items>.slider__item:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.service .slider__checker:nth-child(2):checked~.slider__labels>.slider__label:nth-child(2) {
  background: white;
}

.slider__checker:nth-child(3):checked~.slider__items>.slider__item:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
}

.slider__checker:nth-child(3):checked~.slider__labels>.slider__label:nth-child(3) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="service">
  <div class="slider">
    <input class="slider__checker" type="radio" name="slides" id="#checker1" checked>
    <input class="slider__checker" type="radio" name="slides" id="#checker2">
    <input class="slider__checker" type="radio" name="slides" id="#checker3">

    <div class="slider__items">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="http://www.call4.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/porsche_911_gt3-1920x1080.jpg" alt="..." width="large">
        <div id="head">
          16 bit
          <div class="help">
            <b>Подсказка:</b>
            <p>Это голова</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hand">
          32 bit
          <div class="help">
            <b>Подсказка:</b>
            <p>Это рука</p>
            <a href="http://google.com">Заказать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="foot">
          64 bit
          <div class="help">
            <b>Подсказка:</b>
            <p>Это рука</p>
            <a href="http://google.com">Заказать</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="http://autospynews.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/257833bbf5f552057486de1c87996eee_large.jpeg" alt="..." width="large">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <img src="http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/testdrive/gallery/2014-porsche-911-turbo-s-review-2014_55.jpg" alt="..." width="large">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider__labels">
      <label class="slider__label" for="#checker1">Синий</label>
      <label class="slider__label" for="#checker2">Зеленый</label>
      <label class="slider__label" for="#checker3">Метилик</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: То есть вы где-то слышали, что на веб-страницах можно сделать анимацию, но не знаете, какие CSS свойства для этого используются? Я правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Можно сказать и так. Я читал про анимацию в css, но использовать как-то не доводилось.

Comment: ссылка не работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для начала css-transitions. Там очень простая анимация.

Во-первых, делаете изначальный класс, где указываете параметры до анимации. Также в нем необходимо указать продолжительность и тип затухания анимации, если эти свойства отсутствуют у родителя (например, transition: 250ms ease-in-out).

Во-вторых, делаем класс, который мы будем добавлять к исходному с помощью JS (например, el.classList.add(name)). В нем указывается итоговое состояние объекта после анимации.

Например, если мы хотим сделать перемещение вправо на 100px, то в начальном классе указываем (transform: translate(0px, 0px)), а в классе анимации (transform: translate(100px, 0px)).

Также можно использовать и другие свойства (right, left), но в плане производительности лучше transform, т.к. при этом в большинстве случаев не происходит пересчета макета, браузеру требуется меньше операций для анимации.

Comment: для fade-анимации используйте свойство opacity

Answer (score 0):

В 2012 делал простой слайдер, в материале краткое описание, но должно быть понятно
https://blog.g63.ru/?p=1279
Реализовывал движение слайдов вверх (вниз).
Аналогично влево/вправо делается, как на большинстве слайдеров.

Похожим образом с помощью прозрачности и z-index можно сделать плавное появление/скрытие слайдов.